# Explorer.exe Restore previous folder windows at logon fails

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-explorer

Having the restore option selected in Folder Options works fine, except for vpn drives and virtual (subst) drives that are not initially available at the time explorer.exe tries to connect.

The windows are restored, with an error stating that the target is not availabe (correct, yes, initially), and there is no retry option. Clicking Ok in the dialog just closes the window while leaving it open but contents empty would allow e.g. F5 to refresh... three solutions could be proposed for this (a. delay explorer.exe window restoration; b. add retry button; c. open window empty allowing user to refresh contents later), but none is available (W7, W10).

Any actually working solutions available?